# How can I use the Sitemap page (default) in DXA 1.6 for my custom pages

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.6

Can I use the sitemap page that comes by-default in the CMS when we install DXA 1.6 to display the sitemap navigation for my custom pages that I have created/published  in the CMS.

I linked the page meta schema "Page Navigation Metadata" to my custom page and published it but when I refresh the sitemap page on browser it does not show any entry for my custom pages; its still showing only default DXA pages entries on sitemap page;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this part -" Keywords and Pages need to use a numeric prefix consisting of 3 numbers". Because of this it was not working as its defined in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The DXA site navigation is documented here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-4A757BE5-AED2-4AEE-B9A0-E2A1BEE30C49

There are two ways to implement navigation:

1. Structure Group hierarchy (default)
2. Taxonomy based (a Category and its Keyword hierarchy, which are published)

You set the navigation type while installing the Web application, which must have suitable Navigation Taxonomy in order for the second navigation type to work. In the absence of such a Taxonomy, the system falls back to Structure Group-based navigation.

When using the navigation based on Structure Groups (i.e. the default or fallback), all you have to do to include either a Structure Group or Page to the navigation, is ensure its title starts with a three digit number followed by a space (i.e **020 My Page**). Once the Page is Published, you have to republish the **_Navigation** Page, as described here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-33769114-BCF6-46C2-8FA6-24F1FD88E444

The Page metadata Schema "**Page Navigation Metadata**" is part of the Taxonomy-based navigation. Navigation is then based on the Category called **Sitemap [Navigation]** (part of the **400 Example Site** Publication). In order for a Page to appear in the navigation, it would need to be associated with one or more Keywords from the Category (through the **Page Navigation Metadata** Schema), and after making changes (either in the heirarchy or adding removing Pages from the navigation) you will have to republish the Category.

Comment: DXA 1.6 does come with a "Page Navigation Metadata" Schema which can be used to classify Pages against the Sitemap Taxonomy (used fot Taxonomy-based navigation).

Comment: @RickPannekoek thanks, I found it in the **110 DXA Site Type** Publication, where I would have expected it in the **100 Master** Publication along with all the other Schemas.